# where is the javascript `default_frontend.js` included in TYPO3 11?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

We have a TYPO3 V11 installation where the backend is protected by htaccess.

Now we have a problem that in the FE some pages also require the htaccess login as on these pages a file `/typo3/sysext/frontend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/default_frontend.js` is included:

```html
<script async="async" src="/typo3/sysext/frontend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/default_frontend.js?1676362612"></script>
```

As editors (and me) have a login for changes in the backend we have no problems, but pure frontend visitors without editor access require a login which is not available for them.

I can't find anything in common for these pages, and why other pages don't include this file.
I can't find where this file is required and set to include. So I can't change the file location or change the mode of inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inserted via `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\DefaultJavaScriptAssetTrait` and can be deactivated via [`config.removeDefaultJS`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#removedefaultjs)

Comment: I tried it (in the 'setup') and it failed. Until I found this setting is needed in the 'constants' part.

Comment: That sounds strange... Normally every constant value is inserted in the setup and PHP uses only the values of the setup... Sure, there's no extension setting the TS value or inserting the constant (and overriding you TS-setup)?